# In the Walking Dead, has the rest of the world already starved to death?

Tags: the-walking-dead

Because of the abundance of supermarkets, stockpiled canned goods and weapons in the USA (survivalists come to mind. Do they actually even exists outside the USA?) , is it safe to assume that those inhabitants are the only people in the world with any kind of chance in such an apocalypse?

Comment: I have heard that other countries have supermarkets and canned food too. Problem is that eventually it will run out too (canned food doesn't **grow** in supermarkets), if there is actually much left after the riots and looting in the aftermath of the zombie apocalypse.

Comment: That all depends on how many people are left. I would think that the USA has more food floating around than Ethiopia for example. It could last decades

Comment: Per Glenn: "Everything left in this world is hidden." Even in the USA there are very few canned goods left.

Comment: Are you asking if *survivalists* exist outside the US, or if supermarkets and stockpiled goods/weapons exist outside the US?

Comment: What about gathering food from other sources? Is it easier to hunt or grow your own food in Ethiopia? What about European countries? Does that apply to Australia? And, is the American midwest the same as the West coast or East coast for any of these criteria? Number of supermarkets and bullets can't be the only decisive advantage for survival.

Comment: @phantom42 take a wild guess. It wasn't that poorly phrased was it?

Comment: Grammar rules state that you're asking about survivalists since they're mentioned within the same set of parenthesis, but other comments are about the existence of grocery stores in other countries.

Comment: @phantom42 let's go with the grammar rules in that case. Thanks for playing

Comment: I'm going to flag this one as off-topic, the availability of supermarkets in various countries is hardly science fiction material.

Comment: The rest of the world has supermarkets too.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about supermarkets and survivalists outside of the US, not about sci-fi.

Answer (score 6):

Not in the least. [Food reserves are maintained](http://www.momagri.org/UK/focus-on-issues/Food-reserves-in-practice_784.html) in other countries, supermarkets are by no means isolated to the United States, and weaponry exists in other countries. Yes, the United States leads in guns in many ways, but melee weapons have also proven quite useful.

Comment: I'm sure most people are aware that supermarkets are by no means isolated to the United States, thanks for sarcastically pointing that out... Do you think that they are as commonplace or as big everywhere else though? Not to mention corner stores etc. I think not

Comment: The United States has approximately one supermarket for every 100 square miles. The United Kingdom has approximately one supermarket for every 15 square miles. Assuming an even distribution (probably a bit unfair since the United States has a lot of wide open spaces), the United Kingdom has a higher density of supermarkets.

Comment: leave out the deserts, vast forests and Alaska and then?

Comment: :) Sorry, but this is reaching the edge of my ability to do BOE calculations via data in Google.

Answer (score 4):

Since Gabriel has just appeared on the show, and he was alone for the entire time, then it is unlikely that he was the only person left in the world that survived alone.

There may be many remote places all over the world which are unaffected, or had a minimal impact such as island nations. It is conceivable that there are places that are thriving.

Canned food can last decades, so it is also conceivable that there are many people all over the world that is surviving on canned food, and/or living off the land.

Answer (score 1):

Wait, are you asking if supermarkets exist outside the US or if survivalists exist outside the US?  The answer would be yes to both.  For supermarkets, how do you think people get their food?  Do you think they all wear loin cloths and still hunt with spears?  The US isn't the only developed country on the planet.  For survivalists, yes, every country has their own stock of crazy survival 'experts'.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not safe to make that assumption. The "Walking Dead: The Alien" one-shot comic features survivors (including Rick's brother Jeffery Grimes) in Barcelona, Spain. The main series never reveals the fate of the world outside a few states of the USA, so we can only speculate but access to guns and canned food are not necessarily the only ways people could survive. Smaller, geographically isolated countries without land borders (e.g. Iceland, New Zealand) may have been able to contain the outbreaks. People may be surviving in areas of extremes like deserts and semi-arctic areas where zombies movement would be restricted. There are many parts of the world with relatively low population density and edible plants and wildlife where it would probably be easier to survive than the parts of USA shown in the TV show. Equally though we could also speculate that in fact every single person outside the USA has died, but this seems less likely than there being small numbers of survivors like Rick's group hanging on here and there.